# Macro code from Excel 2003 doesn't work in 2007

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2007

This code works well in Excel 2003 but fails in Excel 2007.  What am I not seeing in it that crashes it? It errors out when it gets to the **"LastRow ="**..  This is my error message:
     **Run-Time Error 13        Type Mismatch**

```
 Dim LastRow As Long
 Dim LastColumn As Integer
 Dim LastCell As Range, NextCell As Range

'  ****************************************************
    '  Finds LastRow and LastColumn
    With Worksheets("DB")
     '  Find Last Row/Col
          If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
     ' Search for any entry, by searching backwards by rows
             LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
     ' Search for any entry, by searching backwards by columns
             LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
                 SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
                 SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
          End If
       Set NextCell = Worksheets("DB").Cells(LastRow + 1, (LastColumn))
    End With
 '  ****************************************************
```

Found an error. Guess I copied the **Lastrow** and was GOING to change the second one to columns. but that still doesn't solve the hang on the first chunk.  Opps while editing that last part to columns I see that I may have typed an extra "s" in the **.Rows** Looks like it SHOULD be **.Row**  I'll see when I get home since my hard copy at work shows no "s". Guess that's what I get when trying to "Remember" the code when I get home.  To "s" or not to "s", that is the question.  LOL  At least I think I solved it with a little poke the the head.  Thanks Siddharth.

Comment: `LastRow` is of type `Long` but it appears that the call to `Cells.Find()` is not coming up with a `Long` value.  Has the spreadsheet against which you are running this VBA macro changed as well?

Comment: @Tim Nothing has changed. Just copying code for use at home, to allow for testing I have a populated a sheet I am using as a log similar to one at work, it just fails at that point. Going to try the suggestion from Siddharth when I get home. I know there are a few differences in the transportability from 2003 to 2007/10 and as a novice programmer I am still figuring that out. I wind up doing the same code at home on a newer version of Excel to proactively rewrite my code for work if and when we switch to a newer version, so I am ready for the changeover with relatively little headache.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure it works with Excel 2003?

You have to use `.Row` instead of `.Rows`. See [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba)

Your code will also fail because your `LastColumn=0`

Is this what you are trying?

```
Sub Sample()
    Dim LastRow As Long
    Dim LastColumn As Integer
    Dim NextCell As Range

    With Worksheets("DB")
        If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
            '~~> Find Last Row
            LastRow = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

            '~~> Find Last Column
            LastColumn = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], _
            SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column
        End If

        '~~> Set the cell to the first empty cell after the last cell
        '~~> which has data
        Set NextCell = Worksheets("DB").Cells(LastRow + 1, (LastColumn))

        '~~> Display the address of that cell
        MsgBox NextCell.Address
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @ Siddharth I am using this code at work on several files that save to separate log sheets. Needing the last row this works really well in 2003 Excel. But when I try using the code on my Excel 2007 it fails. I have been using the code for over 10 months now without fail until it was tried on 2007. I'll give the **.Row** to **.Rows** a try when I get home.